# форматирование кода при создании snippet sublime text3

Tags: sublime-text-3

создаем сниппет:

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
<div class="">
${1}
</div>
]]></content>
<!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
<tabTrigger>dc</tabTrigger>
<!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
<!--    <scope>source.html</scope>-->
</snippet>
```

при вызове закрывающий div уезжает вправо на 2 tab. Как отформатировать вывод? Спасибо

Comment: я вставил Ваш код — у меня закрывающий `div` при вызове отобразился в начале строки. Подозреваю, что после открывающего дива был знак табуляции, который сюда не скопировался.

Answer (score 1):

при создании сниппета не допускать лишних пробелов и табов. Это все отражается на форматировании выходного кода. То есть, в этом случае создать сначала так:

```
<div class=""></div>
```

а потом выставить в нужное положение закрывающий div